# re: 3ware raid 10 (4drive) suggested stripe size suggestions?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware-raid

looked around on the site but nothing really concrete on my question.

i will have about 120GB of data total, files are made up of 5MB files, excel, word and about 25 .pst files that are about 1.2GB each. Yes they use .pst over network, even though it is not recommended this is legacy setup without issue so we will continue to support this for another year or so. I need to know what you think about a stripe size of 256kb for the raid 10 based on the above requirements. I did try and bench with these settings and it seems alright without any real issue, just trying to rule out anything i might of missed.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to rule out here. 64kb or multiplies are recommended. if that is for PST files, ensure:
* Proper partition alignment to 64kb
* NTFS file system with NODE size 64kb

to minize the overhead and totally eliminate split reads / writes.

Depends a lot on the average file size how much space loss a 64kb node size is. I use that basically for serer partitions (exchange, SQL) where no significant number of small files exist.

If you hav a lot of small stuf in there - normal settings are also ok, you just will get split IO for the larger files.